# Laravel Passport Install Class Not Found

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm trying to configure my Laravel app to use Passport and have gotten stuck at loading the class in my AppServiceProvider.php. Here is what I've done...

```
<?php // AuthServiceProvider.php

namespace S1\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as 
ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
...
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();
        Passport::tokensCan([
            'client' => 'this is a api client test'
        ]);
    }
}
```

.

```
<?php .  // auth.php
 ...
return [

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
             'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
], ...
```

.

```
<?php // app.php

'providers' => [
...
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
....
```

.

```
<?php  // AppServiceProvider.php

namespace S1\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use S1\Providers\AppServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        // Enable Laravel Migrations Generator for development only
        if ($this->app->environment() !== 'production') {
            $this->app->register(\Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class);
            $this->app->register(\Xethron\MigrationsGenerator\MigrationsGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is getting the following error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'S1\Providers\Passport' not found
```

I did have this working but had to rebuid and now I can't get past this error. Something is going on with my namespaces but I can't figure out what.

Comment: write this on the top of your imports 'use Laravel\Passport\Passport;'

Answer (score 41):

In your `AuthServiceProvider.php`, change:

```
use Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider;
```

to:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

Answer (score 10):

Seems like you forgot to import passport, Try adding this

```
use App\Passport\Passport;
```

to your AppServiceProvider

```
<?php  // AppServiceProvider.php

namespace S1\Providers;

use App\Passport\Passport;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use S1\Providers\AppServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        // Enable Laravel Migrations Generator for development only
        if ($this->app->environment() !== 'production') {
            $this->app->register(\Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider::class);
            $this->app->register(\Xethron\MigrationsGenerator\MigrationsGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Please check your ***composer.json***, did the laravel/passport include it or not into "require" like this :

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
 },
```

if not re-run

> composer require laravel/passport

Answer (score 4):

Install the proper `Passport` version for your specific `Laravel` version. Say you have Laravel 5.5, install Passport 4.0:

`composer require laravel/passport=~4.0`

To check your Laravel version:

`php artisan --version`

or see `"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",` under the require object in `composer.json`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: i waste over it about two hours after that i have add  { use Laravel\Passport\Passport; }  on authservice provider and problem is solved laravel official documantation has missed it.

Comment: Consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code and adding an explanation.

Comment: just the import use Laravel\Passport\Passport; was missing

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem after running this command in console:

```
composer require dusterio/lumen-passport:*
```

Then I found all classes for passport laravel or/and lumen.