# Undefined type 'App\Providers\Passport' laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

I've follow the installation instruction to Install passport from the laravel official documentation and the installation completed successfully, but when I try to add passport routes method within the boot method of my App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider its give me this error **Undefined type 'App\Providers\Passport'**

here is my **composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
    "laravel/passport": "^10.2",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

here is my **AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
  <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();
    

    }
}
```

I don't know what is the problem

Comment: see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787458/laravel-passport-install-class-not-found

Comment: why did you comment : // use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

Comment: because it's not working so I comment it

Comment: Tried running composer dump-autoload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=>remove the comment then run.
protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];
```

Comment: thank you passport work now, can I know why this prevent passport to work

Comment: for user who don't use policy and didn't have the file in that location, that error log will consistently came out. it's best if you have some kind of handler for this.The policy mappings for the application